# Зачем при переопределении equals после сравнения классов делать приведение типов сравниваемых объектов?

Tags: java

В процессе изучения Java столкнулся с темой переопределения метода equals. Во всех гайдах на эту тему встречается такая последовательность:

```
if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
        return false;
}

Person guest = (Person) obj;
```

Я понимаю смысл сравнения классов при сравнении объектов, но зачем дальше, зная что классы объектов и так идентичны, приводить один объект к типу другого?

Comment: Чтобы потом объекты сравнивать по полям класса Person (например, по id, имени, фамилии и т.д.). У object этих полей нет.

Comment: Почитайте, что происходит при восходящем и нисходящем преобразованиях, там ничего сложного, но знать нужно

Comment: Прошу прощения, еще не разобрался с механикой ответов. Как ответить на конкретный комментарий, не знаю. Еще раз напишу тут самую непонятную для меня мысль. Мы уже сравнили эти два объекта на принадлежность к одному классу и получается, что obj.getClass() == this.getClass(). Получается, что obj и так (Person). Зачем приведение?

Comment: И спасибо про наводку про восходящее и нисходящее преобразования. Пошел читать.

Comment: `Получается, что obj и так (Person). Зачем приведение?` - затем, что мы только проверили, что объект относится к классу Person, но этого недостаточно - чтобы получить доступ к полям класса Person, нужно явно привести объект к этому классу. Ответить на комментарий нельзя, можно упомянуть пользователя по нику, например так: @АндрейКопылов

Answer (score 1):

- При переопределении метода мы используем тот же тип аргументов, что и в оригинальном методе (Object), иначе это будет перегрузка (@Overload)
- Так вот. переопределяя equals(), мы используем тип Object, то есть передаваемый аргумент принимает этот тип.
  Но переданный объект все равно будет относится к классу, которому принадлежал. Тоесть есть смысл сравнить классы.
- Только если не сделать приведение типов, то поля объектов, необходимых нам для сравнения, будут недоступны.
- То есть ты делаешь низходящее приведение типов от object к необходимому типу.
  Попробуй сам все это в среде разработки и поймешь.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой развернутый ответ! Благодаря указанию в комментариях выше про апкастинг и даункастинг. я разобрался, зачем необходимо приведение, но возник вопрос про обжект в аргументе и тут ваш ответ расставил все точки над i окончательно.